# Using a contextual filter as a search term

Tags: views

I'm attempting to allow users to search for titles of a specific content type in a view. I'd like to be able to pass a search term into a contextual filter but I can't seem to get that to work.

Right now I have a view filter for 'title' that is set to contains 'any word'. I also have a contextual filter that looks for title, but passing any word to it results in the view displaying nothing. I also noticed that there was a 'search term' filter but every time I used that no results were shown.

EDIT: If I'm unable to pass it via a contextual filter, would I be able to have the view filter grab the parameter from the URL via REST?